# VBA MSWord 2007 - Insert text at line 7

Tags: vba, text, insert, ms-word, line

I'm moving data from one document to another. I need to move the data and already have it as a string. I just don't know how to put it in the other word document.

The following is getting the text.

```
'finds a range of text between the words "Purpose" and "Scope" and makes it strThePurpose
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.Find.Text = "Purpose"
blnFound = Selection.Find.Execute
If blnFound Then
    Selection.MoveLeft wdWord
    Set rng1 = Selection.Range
    Selection.Find.Text = "Scope" 'changed here 2014-18-04 from "7.0 Revisions:" to "Revisions:"
    blnFound = Selection.Find.Execute
    If blnFound Then
        Set rng2 = Selection.Range
        Set rngFound = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start, rng2.Start)
        strThePurposeText = rngFound
        'MsgBox (strTheText)

    End If
End If
```

I just don't know how to put it in the word document at a specific line in the template file.

---

#### Solved

Answer that seems to work:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=7, Name:=""
Selection.TypeText Text:=strTheRefDocsText
```

---

#### Solved better

A better and more effective approach is to insert a bookmark in word and insert at the bookmark into the word template.

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bmBeginningOfDocument"
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bmBeginningOfDocument"
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
```

I used the above code as a better idea on how to get to the location.